# How to check whether a user has entered the wrong value when navigating through a Terminal I/O?

Tags: c++, input, io, terminal

Here is an example program that executes a terminal IO navigation technique. I am looking to try and check whether the user has entered a wrong value.

```
// This program simply demonstrates nagivating through a Terminal I/O
// whilst checking that the user has not entered the wrong value for nagivation

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string user_input;

    cout << "Would you like to withdraw (W) from or deposit (D) into your Bank Account?";
    cin >> user_input;
    // Here I would like to check whether the user has entered some wrong value - say "e", "f", or even "glirebglhbgeriuub",
    // and if they have entered the wrong value, they get an error message and asked to enter again
    // I would also like to know how to use a more generic incorrect user input detection method
    // Any ideas?

    # Do other things here depending upon whether the result was "W" or "D"...

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT: This is what I have tried in the past, however I am not sure whether it is the best way to do this:

```
cout << "Would you like to withdraw (W) from or deposit (D) into your Bank Account?" << endl;
cout << "-> ";
cin >> user_input;

while ((user_input != "W") && (user_input != "D"))
{
    cout << "Would you like to withdraw (W) from or deposit (D) into your Bank Account?" << endl;
    cout << "-> ";
    cin >> user_input;
}

if (user_input == "W")
{
    // DO STUFF
}
else if (user_input == "D")
{
    // DO STUFF
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far and why it didn't work?

Comment: I have seen multiple ways of going about this, most of which involve using a form of a while-loop. I am curious whether there is a 'standard' of sorts when checking whether the user has entered correct inputs.

Comment: _" I am curious whether there is a 'standard' of sorts "_ No, there isn't. You do whatever fits best for you.

Comment: Rather than check for a wrong value, check for the correct values, and if no correct values are found, assume its wrong.

Comment: Is it specific c++ syntax you are after? There are many ways to do this. Look into 'if' conditionals and 'switch' statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try using conditional statements:

```
if(user_input == "W")
{
   //do stuff
}
else if(user_input == "D")
{
   //do different stuff
}
else
{
   //invalid input message
}
```

Based simply off of your question I am not sure what you have and haven't tried, so here is the simple and sweet solution to user input sanitization.

Answer (score 0):

You have unneeded duplicate code.  Just make user that user_input is empty , the obvious default, and go directly to your loop.

```
std::string user_input;

while ((user_input != "W") && (user_input != "D"))
{
    cout << "Would you like to withdraw (W) from or deposit (D)"
            " into your Bank Account?\n-> ";
    cin >> user_input;
}
```

To me, the second conditional is redundant, based upon the while loop.

```
if (user_input == "W")
{
    // DO W STUFF
}
else { // if must be "D"
    // Do D stuff
}
```